# Is there any way to create thumbnails in the Trash folder?

Tags: 14.04, trash, thumbnails

By default these do not seem to be generated. I don't know if I can force the system to do it as they would be very handy to identify a wrongly deleted picture. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not possible. There is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-exe-thumbnailer/+bug/673251) marked for it (with no actions on it since 2010) and an [Ubuntu forums topic](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2258403) from 2006 with no response on it. So no would be my answer.

But there is an alternative: use "viewer" and open trash from it. It will show a preview in the right pane.

[image: screenshoot]

Comment: This seems to be a good workaround but I'm not getting the preview of any image (not just in the Trash folder). When you say "viewer" do you mean the "eog" viewer?

Comment: Yes. "viewer" in dash (that used to be eog iirc.).

Comment: Just tried and I don't get the right panel with the previews... :-/ There must be a related setting somewhere but that is a different issue anyway. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ohh it might be new in 14.10 :D You are using 14.04 :)

Answer (score -1):

You could use other available file managers. I would suggest you to use Dolphin. Install it by typing sudo apt-get install dolphin. It will definitely work.